# What is index in load static?

Tags: django, jinja2

please tell me what is the index in
`{% load static index %}`?

This came across to me in someone else's code. I didn't find anything like this in the documentation

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#load) the other guy loads the packages `static` and `index`, tho I have no idea what is defined in them.

Comment: `index` is a template tag library used by that project. You need to study the code in its entirely to make sense of it.

Comment: @solarissmoke, thank you all for your help friends!